# How to use Perl Exceptions?

Tags: perl, exception

I have a Perl problem of the following kind:

```
$object1 = $ABC->Find('test1');
```

Then I want to call a subroutine called `CheckResult` in `Report.pm`:

```
$Report->CheckResult($object, "Finding the value");
```

In another case I want to report if a particular command was executed, so I do something like this:

```
$Report->CheckResult($ABC->Command(100,100), "Performing the command");
```

Now in `Report.pm`:

```
sub CheckResult {
    my ($result, $information) = @_;
    # Now, I need something like this
    if ($result->isa('MyException')) {
        # Some code to create the report
    }
}
```

How do I use exception class and how to check if an exception is raised, and if so perform the task necessary?

---

Edit:

As of now, I have a module of the kind:

```
package MyExceptions;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exception::Class (
    'MyExceptions',
    'MyExceptions::RegionNotFound'     => {isa => 'MyExceptions'},
    'MyExceptions::CommandNotExecuted' => {isa => 'MyExceptions'}
);
```

The other module is:

```
package ReportGenerator;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub CheckResult {
    my ($result, $info) = @_;

    # Here is want to check of $result and throw an exception of the kind
    # MyExceptions::RegionNotFound->throw(error => 'bad number');
    # I'm not sure how to do this
}
1;
```

The user would in turn script something like this:

```
$Report->CheckResult($ABC->Command(100,100), "Tapping Home");
```

Could someone help? Sorry about my ignorance, I haven't done exceptions at all.

Comment: I think Exception::Class will suit my need, could someone tell me how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is no help if you throw an exception and the user runs code that does not catch it. The code for [`Exception::Class`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exception%3a%3aClass) is quite simple:

```
# try
eval { MyException->throw( error => 'I feel funny.' ) };

# catch
if ( $e = Exception::Class->caught('MyException') ) {
    ...
```

Thus, it shows both the throwing code and the client code. The `eval` line is both "try" and "throw" syntax. The rest is catching. So in a sort of highlevel regurgitation of your specs it would look something like this:

```
if ( !Object->find_region( $result )) { # for OO goodness
    MyExceptions::RegionNotFound->throw( error => 'bad number' );
}
```

Your client code would simply test--I recommend actually testing (and *freezing*) `$@` first.

```
eval { 
    $Report->CheckResult($ABC->Command(100,100), "Tapping Home");
};
if ( my $ex = $@ ) { # always freeze $@ on first check
    my $e;
    if ( $e = Exception::Class->caught('MyExceptions::RegionNotFound')) { 
        warn( $e->error, "\n", $e->trace->as_string, "\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Axeman.. could you explain this line if ( !Object->find_region( $result ))

Comment: @MarsMax: pseudocode of "check of $result", just in OO terms `find_region` is named simply because the Exception you want to throw is `RegionNotFound`. So if you *don't* find the region indicated by the `$result` die with RegionNotFound.

Comment: Thanks Axeman..I finally got what I wanted...looks like I would not be able to handle different kinds of objects which could be provided by $result..so it wont be needed..the script from the user end..looks something like ` if ( my $ex = $@ ) { my $e; if ( $e = Exception::Class->caught('MyExceptions::ExecutionException')) { print $e->message; } } ` and then the exception was thrown something like ` MyExceptions::ExecutionException->throw( message => $data )`

Answer (score -2):

in Report.pm :

```
sub CheckResult {
    try {
        $Report->CheckResult($object,”Finding the value”);
    } catch MyException with {
       # Exception handling code here
    };
}
```

Comment: If your code requires a module, please specify this.  Also, a block of code with no explanation is not much of an answer.